# Iframe in lightbox and how to turn off scrolbars from main window

Tags: iframe, scrollbar, lightbox

I have a lightbox at my website. It is a [shadowbox script](http://www.shadowbox-js.com) which opens me an `iframe`. The `iframe` has it's own scrollbars at the right. Is there any way to turn off the scrollbars from main/top window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a `overflow: visible` or a `overflow: hidden` may work?

The `overflow` CSS property specifies what happens when the content inside the element overflows the element.

[See this MDN page for more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/overflow)

---

**UPDATE:** The OP has clarified.

You should use something like this:

```css
#your-lightbox-box-which-has-scrollbars-which-you-do-not-want {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: nah its not that 1st of all it would only hide it so it would still scroll and scrollbars are not a part of website, so I dont think im able to hide them using simple css

Comment: @MichaiłAndriejBogdanow Did you try? Do you want to hide the scrollbars only or mmake the stuff hidden by the scrollbars to be visible?

Comment: most important is to turn them off so it will be unable to scroll and hide them like under the darken layer or something

Comment: Its not working... I gave you the link to this lightbox script so you can check it out by yourself... http://www.shadowbox-js.com/

Comment: so maybe there is a way to turn off the scrollbars ot the iframe and show all the content (height) and than I would be able to scroll this content using the scroll from main/top window? (the content of main/top window should stuck when lightbox is opened).